# Why boost::beast::http::async_write sends one http request in multiple TLS segments?

Tags: c++, ssl, https, boost-beast

I am working on one simple async Https client using boost::beast lib. Boost version is 1.69.0.

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> sslSocket_;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
boost::optional<boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body>> request_;
boost::optional<boost::beast::http::response_parser<boost::beast::http::string_body>> responseParser_;
boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
```

After Tcp connection and tls handshake, everything works fine. However, when we build one http request and send it with boost::beast::http::async_write:

```
void SimpleAsyncHttpsClient::buildHttpRequest(const std::string& uri, const std::string& payload)
{
    request_.emplace();
    request_->set(boost::beast::http::field::host, host_);
    request_->set(boost::beast::http::field::accept, "*/*");
    request_->set(boost::beast::http::field::content_type, "application/json");
    request_->set(boost::beast::http::field::date, "Tue, 01 Jun 2021 07:27:04 GMT");
    request_->set(boost::beast::http::field::connection, "close");
    request_->target(uri);
    request_->method(boost::beast::http::verb::post);
    request_->body() = payload;
    request_->prepare_payload();
}

void SimpleAsyncHttpsClient::sendHttp()
{
    boost::beast::http::async_write(sslSocket_,
        *request_,
        std::bind(
            &SimpleAsyncHttpClient::waitForResponse,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Strangely the such piece of code sends my http request in multiple segments,
[wireshark screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwPwP.png)
[wireshark screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArBQX.png)

The client firstly send "POST", then send the path and then the header lines in each segment.

I've also tried one sync https client and it is the same behavior. However, if we use boost::asio::async_write API we do not have this problem.

Question: How could I send the http request in one packet with boost::beast APIs? The other beast lib(parser, etc) are very friendly to developers.